# Can I use MapPoint in my winforms c# Application

Tags: c#, winforms, mappoint

Can I use MapPoint in my c# Winform Application. I mean I couldn't find good resources on the internet, Microsoft did put some info for developers but I am confused about how I can integrate it in my application.

Purpose:
The purpose of using map is that we need to display vehicles on the map, like on which street they are in UK. Is there any better way to achive this functionality.

Can somebody share their experience on how we can use MapPoint in our c# winform application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the Mappoint 2011 SDK

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674715.aspx

It shows you how to use embed their COM Active X control (which you can do in .NET) and how to call their object model.  The only problem is that all the examples are in VB.NET

This link show how to reference the ActiveX control to your application and a little bit of C# on coding against it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674717.aspx

Since it looks like MapPoint is not being updated (due to very old references even in there 2011 SDK), you may want to look at embedding a browser control in your app and using the bing.com/maps sdk as it will be updated much more frequent and is more up to date in terms of technologies

http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/mapapps.aspx